# What is the difference between an ISO image and Vagrant box?

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

To add a box in Vagrant we add the below code in a vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|

  config.vm.box = "hashicorp/bionic64"

end
```

Can we also add an ISO image instead of a box? If yes, then what is the way? And why do we need to build a box in Vagrant - why can't we use an ISO image?

Answer (score 1):

> Can we also add an ISO image instead of a box

No, you can't. Box contains more information Vagrant needs to run the guest on given provider (and you need different box for different provider, i.e. virtualbox, etc), than ISO image can provide (see [Box File Format](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/boxes/format.html)). You can use ISO image to install whatever needed on yiur guest and then make the box file out of it or make box out of ISO using additional tools though.

Comment: Can you point me to the link where I can see what all information a box contains for Vagrant?